# Resque - how to cancel an ongoing job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

Once a Resque job is picked up by a worker and started execution, is there a way to make it stop?

I'm implementing couple Resque jobs, and when a new one starts, I want it to check the currently running ones and stop those that will create conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Resque-status provides ability to kill worker jobs with `Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.kill(job_id)`

For more info: Refer https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status#kill-kill-kill